# Tesseract Api Linker Error with Using Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, tesseract

I am using tesseract api and my project(I am using vs2013c++) has just tesseract api I have no porblem On the other hand I am using opencv nd my project has just opencv I have no problem But I want to use together them I have LINK error but I m sure that I added libraries correctly()
[image]

[image]

[image]

Those are the error messages:

```
error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals  
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI(void)" (??0TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main   
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl tesseract::TessBaseAPI::~TessBaseAPI(void)" (??1TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
```

Comment: Please paste the actual text, not screenshots, because it's easier for us to search about the error in google and come up with suggestions.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer